# IIS7 shortcut redirects to original location

Tags: windows, git, iis-7, symlink, shortcut

I'm using git to test out a dojo widget I'm developing.  I am developing this with someone on a *nix machine and I'm running into issues with how everything is put together.

dojo is organized by a folder convention and git wants everything to be inside a single folder. The other coder on *nix is using symlinks to place the files where they need to be within the dojo folder structure but creating shortcuts to these files on windows, which i see as being the windows equivalent, causes IIS to redirect to the shortcut origin location breaking all of the relative paths within the file.  Is there a more proper way to do this since coping pasting the files where they need to be from the git repository is a PITA. Is there a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using actual symbolic or hard links in Windows, it might give you better luck.

Depending on OS, you may already have this functionality available (e.g. the `mklink` command in Windows 7 and I believe Vista as well); in Windows XP there is a `junction` command available as a powertoy (but junctions apply only to directories): http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768

There are also a few shell extensions that enable access to symlink/junction functionality as right-click menu items in explorer:

- http://elsdoerfer.name/ntfslink (I use this regularly in XP)
- http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html (I've used this with success in Win7)

Comment: using mklink with the /h command works as you would expect. Thanks kgf.